# Can not install hcluster from pypi under python 2.6 on xp

Tags: python, hcluster

I am using the setup.py file supplied with hcluster with the following lines added:

```
sys.path.append("c:\\Program Files\\Python26\\Lib\\site-packages\\hcluster-0.2.0")
sys.path.append("c:\\Program Files\\Python26\\Lib\\site-packages\\hcluster-0.2.0\\hcluster")
```

Then used setup.py as follows:

> "c:\program files\python26\python.exe" "c:\Program Files\Python26\Lib\site-packages\hcluster-0.2.0\setup.py"  install

I get the following error messages:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'hcluster' does not exist
```

Don't know if it trying to read or write hcluster.

Any help appreciated

Comment: pls refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412518/how-to-build-install-hcluster

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to add packages in site-packages in sys.path.
2. **Did you copy the hcluster in site-package manually? It is not the correct way to do it.**

   2.1 You should have the hcluster outside the site-packages say in your home directory and then run "python setup.py install"

   2.2 This will put the package after build into site-package directory. This is where all external package reside by default after they are installed.
3. Remove the folders related to hcluster from site-packages and install with instruction 2.
4. Read the following to understand your error: http://docs.python.org/install/index.html